# Why strLikeText is returns false when compare text with "#"?

Tags: c#, vb.net, string

I used like the below code to compare two strings, but why it is always returns false,

```
string s1 = "#a";
string s2 = "#a";
bool b1 = Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.StringType.StrLikeText(s1,s2);
```

Comment: Please add the [visual-basic] tag.

Comment: lots of ways to do it without that library which I'm not familiar https://dotnetfiddle.net/f0Nphf

Comment: "This API supports the product infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code. ", from the docs on `StrLikeText`

Answer (score 0):

As noted in Eris' comment, `StrLikeText` is intended for internal use only.

There are many better ways to compare strings. For example:

```
var s1 = "test";
var s2 = "test";

var result = s1 == s2; // true
var result2 = s1.Equals(s2); // also true
```

Take a look at [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165449.aspx) on string comparisons.